# Issue with connecting a present viewController to nextViewController

Tags: swift, uistoryboardsegue

I downloaded the starter project from [HERE](http://www.appdesignvault.com/custom-transition-slide-out-navigation/)

But when I try to Ctrl+Drag from the TimelineViewController to the NavigationViewController to create a segue simply I can not do that like this:

[image]

I don't understand what is the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a segue, you need to control+click from the trigger of the segue (button, link, etc.) to the new view controller. A view controller cannot trigger a segue. In keeping with the tutorial, try control+drag from the menu button to the target VC. That will solve your problem, but I don't know how it will affect remainder of the tutorial.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I want to perform this action as suggested into tutorial and I want to know what is the problem here why I can not connect this two with control+drag.